# Need Help with Kitchen Light Switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I have 3 different black hot wires in my kitchen light switch.  I've tried varying different combinations on a single pole and no matter which combination the kitchen switch either turns on the stair lights or the front porch light when turned on and I can't tell which of the 3 is the main.

If I want them all to act independently, do I need a 2, 3 or 4 way switch? The kitchen switch should obviously only turn on the kitchen light lol.

Secondly, if I wanted the kitchen light to be on a dimmer, do they make dimmer switches that allow two other independent hot wires to be connected? If not, no big deal. The 1st question is where I'm stuck.

Comment: I doubt the hot wires are independent.  I suspect two of them are supposed to be connected *to each other*.   I bet the way you found the switch, some wires were on the screw terminals and others were in backstabs.  Each backstab is internally wired to a screw terminal, connecting those to each other.

Comment: Please upload pictures showing all the wires and switches.